# C# PayPal API get balance

Tags: api, paypal, get

How can I get my PayPal balance via .NET PayPal API and my API credentials?

I have already added the API to Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: I have been trying to figure this out as well. Good luck. I heard talks that they actually deprecated the feature of being able to get an accounts balance. I think you have to become a PayPal partner

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer as of now is that <strike>**there isn't an answer**</strike>.

Here is what I *do* know though.

In a discussion [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-REST-API-issues/issues/90), someone claims that there is a whole separate API called [Balance Accounts API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/balance-accounts), but the link is broken or the API is deprecated.

On the GitHub link I linked in this solution you'll see the following dialog between two users:

> @AMRITPK Correct me if I am wrong, but as I see it, this API is only for PayPal partners, for retrieving balances of your internal customers. Or am I mistaken?
>
> > yes @andrey-zav , it works only if the caller is a third party... But work around is you can give permissions to your own account to call this api .. not sure if this is right approach.

So, I'm not really sure what to take out of that.

In addition, you can stay tuned to me fighting the PayPal automated bot-responsive "human" moderators on the PayPal tech support forum [here](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Payouts/How-can-I-get-my-PayPal-Account-Balance-through-the-Payouts-API/m-p/1477664#M86).

As far as I know though, you have to be a PayPal Partner and then use some convoluted way to incorrectly ping your own account via the API to get your PayPal balance account.

I hope this helped.

> **UPDATE:** Through exhaustive searching I found a C# .NET implementation of how to get the PayPal Account Balance using their NVP API [here](https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-dotnet/blob/master/Samples/PayPalAPISample/APICalls/GetBalance.aspx.cs). You'll have to install the [PayPal Merchant Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PayPalMerchantSDK/). In addition, you will have to set up your web config file using the information found [here](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-dotnet/wiki/SDK-Configuration-Parameters). I'm assuming this works on **live** as well. I have only tested it in **sandbox** mode, and it did indeed work.